# Server is responding with status code 504

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, http-status-code-504

I have a next app and I have deploy it on Vercel. The Fronted of the website is working fine but when I send any request to back end (/api/login, /api/games ) it takes some time and fails with status code 504. All is working fine on localhost.

I try to send request with postman on the url 'https://gamezone-9vfc7ufgm-personalusehossain.vercel.app/api/games' but it is also giving me the same result

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out

I have to change the ip address on MongoDB atlas

[image show where to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgPgc.png)